# SQL1159 Initialization error with DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason code 7, tokens 9.1.2.DEF.2, SOFTWARE\IBM\DB2\InstalledCopies

Tags: asp.net, db2

I have a 64 bit machine and have Visual studio 2013 version  connected with DB2 database. I have installed DB 2 data provider in my system . even  though getting the above error.  Any help appreciated .

Comment: This seems more like a question for https://superuser.com. Or is some code causing problems? If so please post it here along with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Give more details about *which version* of the Db2 software you installed, and also what is the Windows version..

Comment: the application was running in 32 bit machine and it was not a code error. error was thrown when  started using the same application  complied in 64 bit with all the db2 softwares

Comment: Db2 run time client  9.1.2 is the db2 provider software. mine is windows 7

Comment: You need to uninstall (remove) the V9.1 runtime client (it is out of support since 2012 and does not support visual studio). You then need to download and install a recent full client for Db2 which has Visual Studio support . Get the "IBM Db2 Data Server Client"  version 10.5 fixpack 9"  or version 11.1  from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24044111  (this is a free download, but IBM registration is required). You go directly to BM's fix central website.